# Using jQuery to set a var equal to a bunch of class's and then hide that variable

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have a bunch of views: .view-1, .view-2, view-3, etc... I was using something hacky like this to get the right view showing when the right item in the navigation was clicked:

```
$(".contact a").click(function() {
    $(".view-1").hide();
    $(".view-2").hide();
    $(".view-3").hide();
    $(".view-4").hide();
    $(".view-5").hide();
    $(".view-6").show();
    return false; 
});
```

But this is difficult to maintain over a bunch of nav item and ever more views.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
 var $allViews = $(".view-1,.view-2");
    $(".how").click(function() {
        $(allViews).hide();
        $(".view-2").show(); 
        return false; 
    });
```

Where I could assign all the view classes

Comment: your pretty close, you could assign 2 classes to your nav elements class="views view-2" and you can use code similar to the above that first hides "view" and then shows "view-2".  You could also assign a class to your parent that you use to hide all children.  Lots of ways to solve this!

Comment: do you really need unique class name for each element?

Comment: What does your html look like? There might be an alternative approach worth considering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about :

`var $allViews = $("[class|='view']")`

Gets all elements with classes equal to 'view' or starting with 'view' followed by a hyphen

Or:

`var $allViews = $("[class^='view-']")`

Gets all elements with classes that start with 'view-`

`$allViews.hide()` would hide all of those elements.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Af9M3/

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a function hideViews(views) { // views.hide(); }  or even use the filter to hide the views except the clicked one? You could get at which view was clicked from the click event.